# Vector identity of the convective term of Navier-Stokes equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, differentiation, vector-fields, navier-stokes

In the NS, a well known expression of the convective term is

$$\bf v \times (\nabla\times \bf v) =  \bf v\cdot \nabla v - \frac{1}{2}\nabla v^2 $$

In order to derive it I use the commute rule of the vectors cross products:

$$\bf a\times (b\times c) = (a\cdot c)b - (a\cdot b)c$$

hence I got

$$\bf v \times (\nabla\times \bf v) =  \bf v\cdot \nabla v -  v^2 \nabla$$

This then puzzled me that, can you explain why

$$v^2 \nabla =  \frac{1}{2}\nabla v^2 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a sign error in the question.  Switching to ESN you can write,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{v} \times ( \nabla \times \mathbf{v} ) &\stackrel{esn}{\equiv} \epsilon_{ijk} v_{j} ( \epsilon_{klm} \partial_{x_{l}} v_{m} )\\
&= -\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{mlk} v_{j} \partial_{x_{l}} v_{m}\\
&= -( \delta_{im}\delta_{jl} - \delta_{il}\delta_{jm} ) v_{j} \partial_{x_{l}} v_{m}\\
&= -v_{l}\partial_{x_{l}}v_{i} + v_{m} \partial_{x_{i}} v_{m}\\
&= -v_{l}\partial_{x_{l}}v_{i} + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{x_{i}}( v_{m} v_{m} )\\
&\stackrel{vect}{\equiv} -\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{v} + \frac{1}{2}\nabla(\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v} )
\end{align}
You wrote the correct identity for vector cross products since you can prove,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{a} \times ( \mathbf{b} \times \mathbf{c} ) &\stackrel{esn}{\equiv} \epsilon_{ijk}a_{j}( \epsilon_{klm}b_{l}c_{m})\\
&=-(\delta_{im}\delta_{jl}-\delta_{il}\delta_{jm})a_{j}b_{l}c_{m}\\
&=-a_{l}b_{l}c_{i} + a_{m}b_{i}c_{m}\\
&\stackrel{vect}{\equiv}-(\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} )\mathbf{c} + (\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c} )\mathbf{b}
\end{align}
but you seem to have applied it with an incorrect mapping which has caused a minus sign error.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind is the argument of the $\nabla$ operator - it is usually indicated by the order of the operators, but it may be helpful to mark it explicitly - e.g., by writing an arrow above or below the affected functions. For simplicity I simply use two different vectors, noting that $\mathbf{w}$ is treated as a constant, whereas $\mathbf{v}$ is the argument of the differential operator and should in the final result be placed in the end. Applying BAC-CAB prescription we obtain:
$$\mathbf{w}\times(\nabla\times\mathbf{v}) = \nabla(\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{v}) - \mathbf{v}(\mathbf{w}\cdot\nabla) =
\nabla(\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{v}) - (\mathbf{w}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{v}.
$$
It is now trivial to note that
$$\nabla(\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{v})\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}\nabla(\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{v}).$$